# How to play an audio file through http response in Django

Tags: python, html, django, html5-audio

**I want to know how to play an audio file in the browser**

How to play an audio file in the browser?

Comment: Check this out: https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/

Comment: @A.Takhirov no that's not what I want, I want to play an audio file in the browser.

Comment: no that's not what I want